# can't ping myself after I changed hostname

Tags: ubuntu

I've changed my hostname in `etc/hostname` from `ubuntu` to `ubuntuclient` but now I can't ping myself. as a result I always get `unknown host: ubuntuclient.guf.by`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to change the hostname in the `/etc/hosts` file as well.

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/03/change-hostname-computer-name-ubuntu-11-04-natty/